# It's time we had a talk

Tags: grammaticality, time

I have a misunderstanding with one question. This phrase was said in the present moment, not about the past. That's why I'm confused.

"It's time we had a talk"
I suppose there is the Present Perfect tense. (like "It has time we had to talk")
but for me, if it's said in present it should be like "It is time have a talk"

Can someone explain that to me, please?

Comment: Interesting.  It feels as if it must be a subjunctive.  So I might similarly say:  “It’s time we were introduced.”. My guess is that it is a subjunctive of purpose.  But I shall have to ‘hit the books’ as they say.  Incidentally, have you tried any research to find the answer?

Comment: Here is a similar question from English Language Learners Stack Exchange [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49147/we-have-to-go-it-is-time-we/49148#49148]

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of a past subjunctive being used to express unreality. At first look it doesn't seem like there's anything "unreal" in the sentence, but consider the difference between the following (from [here](https://www.grammaring.com/its-high-time)):

> It's time **to go** to bed
>
> It's time **you went** to bed

The first expresses that bed time is right now, while the second implies that bedtime should already have happened. Because the sentence is not a simple statement of fact ("*this is the time* for us to talk") but a statement of obligation ("we *should* talk/*should have* talked by now"), the subjunctive is used. It's not *necessary* to phrase it this way - "It's time to have a talk" is equally grammatical - but the subjunctive construction conveys that extra implication.

Answer (score 1):

**had**, an auxillary verb with 4 senses: the sense here is *to undergo* [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/have?family=had) sense #2

As in:

> "It's time we (undergo/experience) a talk"

Answer (score -2):

[It's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/the-tangled-history-of-its-and-its) is short for either "it is" or "it has" and has been used for about 400 years. In your case it means "it is". However you have typed it without the apostrophe and with a space which is incorrect.

If you follow the link above to the Merriam Webster page "**The tangled history of its and it's**" you will be able to read a very good explanation of both "it's" (which is an abbreviation of "it is" or "it has") and "its" (which is the neuter possesive pronoun equivalent to "his", "hers" and "theirs". It also describes the differences between them.

Comment: The questioner is puzzled by the tense of ‘had’, not by “it’s’.

Comment: it is past time for a talk, so let us do so.

Comment: This is correct, but ought to be a comment as it polishes the question yet doesn't answer it.